# Play framework ignore following map/flatmap

Tags: scala, playframework, reactive-programming

Is there a way to ignore the following map/flatmap's without `failed`?

This is what I have:

```
  def delete(serverId: UUID) = authAction.async { implicit request =>
    val user = request.user.get
    serverService.findByIdAndUserId(serverId, user.id.get)
      .flatMap{s =>
        if (s.isEmpty) {
          Future.failed(new DeleteFailedException)
          // Can I return a `NotFound("...")` here instead of failed?
        } else {
          Future.successful(s.get)
        }
      }
      .map{s =>
        serverService.delete(s)
      }.map{_ =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(Map("success" -> "true")))
    }
  }
```

When I would return a `NotFound("...")` in the `flatMap` the following `map` would still be executed. Is there a way to ignore the following map/flatmap's?

Comment: `serverService.findByIdAndUserId(serverId, user.id.get)` returns `Seq[Option[_]]` ? Are you sure? Because according name I would expect it returns `Option[_]` and your code looks incorrect completely. Could you confirm please?

Comment: @Evgeny It's an `Option` not a `Seq[Option]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a Future.failed with an exception. you can return an Either. The good thing about either is that you can pattern match on it and then construct the appropriate http response.

```
def delete(serverId: UUID) = authAction.async { implicit request =>
  val user = request.user.get
  serverService.findByIdAndUserId(serverId, user.id.get)
    .flatMap{s =>
      if (s.isEmpty) {
        Left(new DeleteFailedException)
      } else {
        Right(s.get)
     }
   }
   .map{s => s match {
     case Left(notFound) => 
        // construct the Json for failure
     case Right(s) => 
        serverService.delete(s)
        // construct json for success.
   }}
 }
```

Comment: What a value to introduce Either instead of already presented Option?

Comment: If the datatype is Option[Int] where int is the user ID which was looked up. then you cannot return a NotFound. because the data types won't match.

Comment: No. First of all, according original code and `flatMap` to `Future`, your code with `Either` will not work. Second, this `flatMap` is basically redundant. It should be removed completely and pattern matching should be done against `Option` (`None`/`Some`) in `map`

Answer (score 1):

Think so should be fine (I assumed that `findByIdAndUserId` returns Future[Option[_]], not an `Option[_]` as you answered in comment). In my approach I also removed usage of `get` and unnecessary `map`

```
def delete(serverId: UUID) = authAction.async { implicit request =>
  val user = request.user.get

  request.user.flatMap(_.id).fold {
    Future.successfull(NotFound("no user"))
  } {userId =>
    serverService.findByIdAndUserId(serverId, userId).map {
      case None =>
        NotFound("no server")
      case Some(s) =>
        serverService.delete(s)
        Ok(Json.toJson(Map("success" -> "true")))
    }
  }
}
```